# MySQL service on local computer started and then stopped

Tags: mysql

Dears;

I have tried to save my.ini file as ANSI after deleting "Unique" comment raw, but the same problem.

even i copied a new my.ini file from a newly installed mysql server 8.0

please help

thank you

[image]

Comment: Look at the Windows Event Log for messages from MYSQL

Comment: Thank you , i have checked the error log file and tyrned out that Tablenamespace id was duplicated for some tables...

Comment: Try to run your Windows terminal (cmd) in administrator and locate the MySQL Server file.

Run this command `mysqld --initialize --console` 

This work for me in MySQL Server 8.0.30 and hope it can help you. After successful initialize you can go to Windows service and start MySQL service